# /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo missing

Tags: 11.04, nvidia, intel-graphics, vgaswitcheroo

i wanted to install and use [asus_switcheroo](https://github.com/awilliam/asus-switcheroo) but unfortunately the vgaswitcheroo folder is missing.
I already checked whether vgaswitcheroo is actually enabled and as i use the vanilla kernel it is (2.6.38-11-generic).

[EDIT]
After looking a bit further into it it seems to help some people to enable kms on intel and radeon drivers to have the folder. Using this [ubuntu forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1159210) post, add the following entries to the following file:

```
gksudo edit /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
```

Then add the following:

```
i915 modeset=1
nouveau modeset=1
```

close and run following command:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

this lets the folder vgaswitcheroo appear again in debug (after reboot)
however after installing asus-switcheroo and rebooting that folder will disappear again.
with disabling:

```
i915-jprobe
nouveau-jprobe
```

which asus-switcheroo adds to `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules`

the directory reappears again, this solution however does not seem consistant and using this [solution](http://hybrid-graphics-linux.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Asus_switcheroo) did not work either unfortunately however temporarely i could live with running:

instead i do this at the moment:
at startup

```
cd /home/user/asus-switcheroo
make install-ubuntu
```

then doing whatever i want to and at shutdown

```
cd /home/user/asus-switcheroo
make uninstall-ubuntu
```

---

possible solution

played a little bit around and it seems that if I remove modeset=1 for nouveau and i915 and install asus-switcheroo it will work however when I echo OFF it does not bring the power saving I wanted but activating nvidia logging out -> in then activating intel logging out -> in saves more energy than using acpi_call.

and the problem with switcheroo disappearing is that it might reappear after a reebot seems rather buggy whether the folder will be available or not.

Comment: there is a similar question here with lots of comments - please look through the comments and answer.  Where there is a question, please add a response to an edit of your question. By doing this means we wont have to ask the same questions.  Thanks.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/53054/i-can-not-find-sys-kernel-debug-vgaswitcheroo-switch

Comment: @fossfreedom i already saw the link before thanks anyway but unfortunatly he solves the problem with enabling switching in the BIOS, this does not exist for the asus ul30vt bios version 211 anymore. I do feel like it could have something to do with [acpi_call] (https://github.com/mkottman/acpi_call) which i disabled for the time being however i will remove it and see whether the folder will appear

Comment: unfortunately removing acpi_call does not change anything if you want any files in the link from fossfreedom just tell me so i can add them to the question

Comment: excellent news - please add this as an answer (and you can accept your own answer) - otherwise the question will just keep going around this system.  Many thanks.

Comment: got a slight problem now after this it works as long as i do not install asus-switcheroo as soon this is installed vgaswitcheroo does disappear again.

Comment: Kurosch - I think you should report your findings as a bug report on asus_switcheroo github.  As you have found - this is alpha quality software.  Hopefully your findings will help the authors of the software to make it better and more robust.

Comment: Although this question is a dupe op http://askubuntu.com/q/53054/6969, you may be interested in alternative solutions for turning the card off, notably Bumblebee+bbswitch: http://askubuntu.com/q/36930/6969

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem: the folder vgaswitcheroo was missing. I found a solution: deactivate all proprietary drivers of your graphic card and then reboot. After that, the folder reappeared onto "/sys/kernel/debug". I hope it will help you !

Comment: Did not help me.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same trouble. Adding the line below to `/etc/fstab` helped.

```
none            /sys/kernel/debug debugfs defaults 0 0
```

You might want to run the line below, to access there without rebooting.

```
mount /sys/kernel/debug
```

Note: There might be other reasons for vgaswitcheroo not showing up additional to this one. In my case other reasons were these;

- I was powering down my discrete gpu on boot, so it wasn't even getting detected. *(vga_switcheroo waits for a second gpu registration to enable itself)*
- For my card (radeon) I also needed to get vbios.bin in three places, /boot, /lib/firmware, and to initramfs