# I can not find /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, vgaswitcheroo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I can not find /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53054/i-can-not-find-sys-kernel-debug-vgaswitcheroo-switch)

Linux segavax-UL80VT 3.0.0-12-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 7 14:56:25 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

where can we find?

Comment: Please provide more clarity to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Either you have enabled modeset in your kernel option in grub while booting or you are not root. If you have not made any changes to boot option then try

```
sudo -i 
cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```