# How to enable vga switcheroo on an Asus U41S?

Tags: nvidia, asus, vgaswitcheroo

I have Asus U41S notebook with 2 wideocards, Intel HD Graphics 3000 and GeForce GT540M. 
I want to turn off the GF videocard, and work only with Intel.

On the internet I found out how to do this with vga_switcheroo :

1. `lspci | grep VGA` to see what number have my videocards
2. `cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` to see what for videocard is active

but terminal says that it can't find locations of /vgaswitcheroo/switch. What must I do?

Answer (score 1):

vga_switcheroo is broken for newer NVIDIA Optimus hardware (this is [fixed in kernel 3.3](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next-history.git;a=commit;h=d099230cc355c485e556121c034b1fca5a5fd18b)). It currently does not survive suspend either (the card remains on after suspend and cannot be disabled/enabled without locking up the system).

I suggest you to take a look at Bumblebee. Since version 3.0, a new power saving feature has been added which can safely disable your discrete video card. More information about this can be found on [Is a NVIDIA GeForce with Optimus Technology supported by Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/36930/6969)