# Do I need to use open source drive of ati for Switcheroo?

Tags: vgaswitcheroo

In ubuntu11.10 , I still need to use open source drive of ATI when using Switcheroo ? The 'addon driver' in system menu is about open drive or propriety driver ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Switcheroo works for open-source drivers only (radeon, i915, nouveau). The *Additional drivers* program tries to install proprietary drivers which do not work with switcheroo.

See also:

- [I can not find /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch](https://askubuntu.com/q/53054/6969)

Comment: In ubuntu 11.10, how to install open source drive of ati Radeon HD 3650? thanks

Comment: Uninstall the `fglrx` driver (and possibly reboot). The radeon driver should be installed by default.